# jQuery handle Ajax timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm trying to catch Ajax timeout error with jQuery 1.4.2, but none of tutorial I found work. In Firebug, when timeout error fires. I see:

> `uncaught exception: [object Object]`.

Please help me handle Ajax timeout. Here's my JS code:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/data/add/",
    data:
    {
    "date":$("input#date").val();
    },
    dataType:"json",
    timeout:2000,
    success: function(response) {
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Server error');
    }
});
```

Comment: You have an errant semi-colon in your data option.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something went wrong again, and i got googled this f*****g bug http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6173 ! here is the spike:

```
success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
    if (!xhr.status) {
        alert("ERROR!!!!");
    }
    else {
        // elided
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I tested this out, and if you remove the `;` from your `$("input#date").val()` statement, it should work.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/data/add/",
    data:
    {
    "date":$("input#date").val()
    },
    dataType:"json",
    timeout:2000,
    success: function(response) {
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Server error');
    }
});
```